# Yang model mandatory node only when condition is true

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, yang

I have an XML file:

```
<a>
    <b>true</b>
    <c>foo</c>
</a>
```

and a Yang model:

```
container a {
   leaf b {
      type boolean;
   }

   leaf c {
      type string;
   }
}
```

Node 'c' is mandatory only when node 'b' equals 'true'. If I add a mandatory: true constraint to node 'c' it will become mandatory for all values of 'b'.

How to change the Yang model so that node 'c' is mandatory when 'b' is 'true' and optional when 'b' is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `must` statement](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.5.3) with an [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-boolean) condition:

```
container a {
   must 'not(b) or boolean(c)'
  
   leaf b {
      type boolean;
   }

   leaf c {
      type string;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yang1.1 support optional mandatory

```
container a {  
   leaf b {
      type boolean;
   }

   leaf c {
      when "../b";
      mandatory true;
      type string;
   }
}
```